# Question on UIScrollView and UIImageViews

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview, ipad

I am making an iPad app that will display six, side by side UIImageViews at once (3 on each line). I want it to be scrollable so I can display up to 15. So its basically like 5 rows of 3 UIImageViews.

I assume I will have to position the UIImageViews programatically and not using IB - is this right? If so, what do I put their positions as? So I know the positions for the first 6 UIImageViews, but what about the rest? And how do I make them appear on UIScrollView in a scrollable manner?

Is there a way to do that using IB too - or is it done all programatically?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

You need to position them in code

You can position a UIImageView like so:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[myScrollView addSubview: image];
```

This creates an image view and places it at 0, 0 in the scrollview with a width and height of 50.

You need to positon your elements like so, then when you get to the elements that will be offscreen you keep going like:

```
UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
image1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1100, 50, 50);
[myScrollView addSubview: image1];
```

This positions the element offscreen in the scrollview

to make the scollview scroll you need to set the contentSize of the scrollview to be bigger than the screen ie. the size of all your elements together

So if you have 6 images that are 500 pixels in height the height on your contentSize will be 6 x 500

To set the content size:

myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

No its not necessary to create images by code you can do it by making a view controller and in its xib add three UIImageView as you want and then use a page control with UIScrollView and for more detail follow the tutorial -

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/

Comment: I actually just drew the whole thing in Interface Builder. The downside here is that I am actually using 15 images instead of reusing 6 images...